# Installation -- No Internet Connection Option

Tags: installation, wireless, internet

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop. I tried to right click on the right hand corner where the internet icon is, and it says Wired Network Disconnected. Below that, I see that *Enable Networking* has a check mark next to it. I clicked on *Edit Connections*, and the name of the wireless connection that I want is listed under the wireless tab, but I don't know what to do.

I have no idea what to do. Am I missing a driver? Is there something that I'm missing? Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, so are many others. I did a little search, discovered this:

http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/10/how-to-fix-unity-and-wireless-problems.html

I have not tried it yet. Seems to work for others though. Good luck.